# Haskell, pattern-matching on lists to get every first element of tuples with arbitrary length

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, tuples

I want to get the first element of every tuple stored in a list like so:

```
INPUT         :   [(1,2,3), (1,4,5), (1,6,7)]
Wanted OUTPUT :   [(1,1,1)]  % Note the tuple notation
```

This is the function I have written so far:

```
f [] = []
f ((x,y,z):xs) = x:(f xs)
```

But it gives me this output:

```
[1,1,1]
```

instead of

```
[(1,1,1)]
```

Where is my misunderstanding?

Comment: You want the result to have type [(Int, Int, Int)] ? You cannot be generic on the length of TUPLES so you should think twice about what you're trying to accomplish. If you are fine with the result being a list (but just want to print to the user the presence of a tuple) then you can pretty print the list with parenthesis.

Comment: why is it not possible to create the searched output? *I am not trying to accomplish something special, i only want to "play around" with the pattern matching for learning purposes.

Comment: Because you can't create a tuple with arbitrary length.

Comment: I see!! Is there any way to make it work if i define that my tuple has 3 elements?

Comment: @MartinM What should happen when your input list has more than three tuples inside it?

Comment: I did not think about that situation... Maybe i should have a seperated function to take 3 elements and put them together into a tuple.

Comment: Yes, you can pattern match on the list directly, don't use recursion. Just pattern match on a list with 3 elements.

Comment: Ah yes, [lists of arbitrary length 3](https://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As yet stated in the comment by @pdexter, you cannot create a tuple with arbitrary length. So what you're trying to do will only work when the tuple exactly pattern matches a tuple with 3 Ints. Let me show you an example to clarify what I mean:

```
helper :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> (Int,Int,Int)
helper xs = (x,y,z)
            where [x,y,z] = f xs

f :: [(Int,Int,Int)] -> [Int]
f []           = []
f ((x,y,z):xs) = x : (f xs)
```

Here we manage to create `(x,y,z)` by pattern matching on `[x,y,z]`, but what if there were more than three tuples, our pattern matching would no longer be valid?

So you should ask yourself the question what it is you're really trying to accomplish with this code and what scenarios might occur (e.g.: empty tuples, tuples with varying lengths mutually, .. ?) and also, how should your program handle these different cases?

If there is no functional reason as to why you like the output to be in a tuple, I suggest you keep the function as is.

Good luck!

Comment: Thats very helpful and now i really understand the problem mentioned in the first place!!